# HTML and CSS: Unable to align the DIV properly

Tags: html, css, web, alignment

Please have a look at the following code.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="styles/cssmenu/menu_source/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="styles/cssmenu2/cssmenu/menu_source/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#apDiv1 {
    position:relative;
    left:750px;
    top:190px;
    width:444px;
    height:43px;
    z-index:0;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="apDiv1"><img src="images/only_text.gif"></div>
<div class="main"> 
  <!------------------------ start menu bar ------------------------->

  <!-- end menu_bar --> 

  <!------------------------ start body_container ------------------------->
  <div class="body_container2">
    <!------------------------ start block_left ------------------------->
    <div class="block_left4" >
      <div class="logo_container">
      <div align="left"><img src="images/only_spiral.gif"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end block_left -->
    <!------------------------ start video_container ------------------------->
    <div class="video_container2">
      <!------------------------ start video ------------------------->
      <div class="video1">
        <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="550" height="300" data-setup="{}" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" preload="none" controls>
          <source type="video/mp4" src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4"></source>
          <source type="video/webm" src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm"></source>
          <source type="video/ogg" src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv"></source>
          <track label="English" srclang="en" src="demo.captions.vtt" kind="captions"></track>
          <!--Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
          <track label="English" srclang="en" src="demo.captions.vtt" kind="subtitles"></track>
          <!--Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
        </video>
      </div>
      <!-- end video -->
      <!------------------------ start div_bottom_video ------------------------->
      <div class="div_bottom_video"> <a href=""><span  id="last2">Menu</span></a> <a href=""><span>Sound</span></a> <a href=""><span>Mail</span></a></div>
      <!-- end div_bottom_video -->
    </div>
    <!-- end video_container -->
    <!------------------------ start presentation_container ------------------------->
    <!-- end presentation_container -->
    <!------------------------ start block_container ------------------------->
    <div class="block_container3">
      <!------------------------ start block1 ------------------------->
      <div class="block1_1">
        <h3>Navigation</h3>
        <ul>
          <a href="">
            <li>Main Page</li>
          </a> <a href="">
              <li>About us</li>
              </a> <a href="">
                <li>Video Samples</li>
                </a> <a href="">
                  <li>Packages</li>
                  <li>Faqs</li>
                  <li>Contact Us</li>
                  </a>
        </ul>
        <hr align="center" width="100%" color="#CCCCCC"/>
        <ul>
        <a href="">          </a><a href="">            </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- end block1 -->
      <!------------------------ start block2 ------------------------->
      <div class="block2_1">
         <div class="presentation_container">
      <embed  width="590" height="auto" src="test.swf" >
      </embed >
    </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end block2 -->
    </div>
    <!-- end block_container -->
  </div>
  <!-- end body_container --> 
  <!------------------------ start footer ------------------------->
  <div class="footer">
    <div id='cssmenu2'>
      <ul>
        <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Main Page</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>About Us</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Video Samples</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Packages</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Faqs</span></a></li>
        <li id='last'><a href='#'><span id="last">Contacts</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <p><span id="format"></span> @ 2008 <a href="">privacy policy</a></p>
  </div>
  <!-- end footer --> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**styles.css**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
/* styles on index.html */
h3 {
    color: #609;
}
.main {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    background-image: url(../images/background6.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.menu_bar {
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    width: 900px;
    padding: 0px 50px 10px 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.body_container2 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 00px 20px 0px 20px;
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}


/*******************************/

.block_left4 {

    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;

}
.logo_container {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
/*******************************/

.video_container2 {
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left:50px;
    width: 550px;
    float:left;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 20px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    left: 650px;
    top: 194px;
    overflow:hidden;
}


.video1 {
    width: 550px;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid thin #999;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #666;
}
.example_video_1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.div_bottom_video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.div_bottom_video span {
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-right: #CCC thin solid;
    color: #609;
}
.div_bottom_video #last {
    border-right: none;
}
.div_bottom_video img {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.div_bottom_video a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*******************************/
.presentation_container {
    float: right;
    width: 590px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
}


/*******************************/

.block_container3 {
    background-color: #666;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    float: right;
    clear:both;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);

}



.block1_1 {
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    clear: both;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.block1 li {
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.block1 a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    list-style: url(../images/bullet.png);
}


.block2_1 {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;

}

/*******************************/
.footer {
    height: 80px;
    width: 900px;
    padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.footer p {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.footer a {
    color: #333;
}
.footer #format {
    color: #09F;
    font-size: 14px;
}
/*******************************/
.link {
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 91px;
    height: 28px;
    background: url("http://dabuttonfactory.com/b.png?t=click%20here&f=Calibri&ts=15&tc=ffffff00&tshs=1&tshc=22222200&it=png&c=7&bgt=gradient&bgc=a27de3&ebgc=471870&be=on&hp=17&vp=9") no-repeat;
    line-height: 28px;
    vertical-align: text-middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-shadow: #222222 1px 1px 0;
}
.link a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.link a:hover {
    color: #CCC;
}
```

My above code generates the below web page.

[image]

You can see how the Video container and the Logo above it (when posting to SO, I removed the logo by painting it using black colour; so the logo is above the video, and that is what you see as a black colour box) in the right side are out of alignments. It is even worse if someone zoomed in or zoomed out the web page, because the video container and logo is getting more and more out of aligned.

Please have a look at the below image.

[image]

The above image shows my expectation. The video and logo are properly aligned and they are not getting out of aligned if the web page is zoomed in or zoomed out.

The name of the DIV which contains the Logo is `apDiv1` and you can find it in line 24 of the HTML code. The name of the DIV which contains the video and all is `video_container2` and you can find it in line 40.

So how can I fix this alignment issue?

Comment: It would really help if you shorten the code blocks to where you think the problem is specifically happening

Comment: @beautifulcoder: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I removed some more code.

Comment: @Hope There is still too much code for the situation. Please include the *minimal* amount of code needed to reproduce the error

Comment: I had a glance at the Css part and noticed you have no rule for "apDiv1", this looks already missing for me. Moreover I think a div around that one and the video_container2 might be useful. Whereas I also would appreciate, if you could highlight some more parts in the code or delete not necessary one.

Comment: Is that the human-centipede?